# Jquery cannot call method replace of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why im getting the error, but i'm getting "cannot call method replace of undefined". It's happening on the the  `$('#wizard'+optionalArg)` part, if I remove the optionalArg part it works fine. Any idea why this is happening?

```
 function loadWizard(optionalArg) 
    {
    optionalArg = (typeof optionalArg === "undefined") ? "" : optionalArg;
    $('#wizard'+optionalArg).smartWizard({contentURL:'/welcome/form_view',
    transitionEffect:'slideleft', onLeaveStep:leaveAStepCallback,onFinish:onFinishCallback, contentCache:false});
    }
```

function call

```
var id = 2;
loadWizard(id);
```

before I send over the ID i run this

```
$('#all_wizards').append('<form action="#" method="POST"><div id="wizard2" class="swMain template"></div></form>');
```

so wizard2 should exist..

Comment: What is $('#wizard'+optionalArg) is returning? Can you do a console.log($('#wizard'+optionalArg)); in chrome or firefox and post the result. If it is undefined then there is no element with that id.

Comment: @TomRiley well if no element is found for the selector then it returns an empty set (`length == 0`) but not `undefined`. Otherwise you could not do `console.log($('#wizard'+optionalArg).length);`

Comment: @t.niese Does it? Fair enough, although [] being spat out would ring similar alarm bells.

Comment: @TomRiley It does. To proofe it with the docs: [`If no elements match the provided selector, the new jQuery object is "empty"; that is, it contains no elements and has .length property of 0.`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: @t.niese No, you should *not* rely on `=== undefined`, since `undefined` is NOT a keyword like `null`. It will compare your value with the variable called `undefined`, which usually noone has defined. In the rare case someone has (accidentally) set the variable `undefined`, the code will break. Testing for `typeof yourvar === "undefined"` will *always* work the way you intend and definitely is the way to go.

Comment: Agreed, in this particular case correct to use `typeof` while direct compare to `undefined` is incorrect, but I believe this is not the reason of exception thrown.

Comment: @RenéWolferink Yes you are right, i removed it. It's time to stop writing comments for today, this mistake should not have happend. (here we ensure the _validity_ of _undefined_ by coding guideline and tests, thats why i missed it) Anyway i should propose to use this test because it ensures the quality by language not by guideline. Bad programming by guideline :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be:

```
$('#wizard'+optionalArg) //would make wizard2
```

there is no element in your html with this id, so calling method on undefine throw exception.

Try with null check:

```
function loadWizard(optionalArg) 
{
   var myElement=$('#wizard'+optionalArg);
   if(myElement.length>0){
       $('#wizard'+optionalArg).smartWizard({contentURL:'/welcome/form_view',transitionEffect:'slideleft', onLeaveStep:leaveAStepCallback,onFinish:onFinishCallback, contentCache:false});
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of jquery plugins just do nothing if selector does not found elements, but maybe smart wizard not smart enough.

Comment: before I pass the argument I run this  `$('#all_wizards').append('<form action="#" method="POST"><div id="wizard2" class="swMain template"></div></form>');`

Comment: A not matching selector returns an empty set and not a string `'undefined'` or `undefined`. So you need to test for: `myElement.length !== 0`

Comment: @Undermine2k should work then, but it's a good idea to check with console.log or in debugger that element exists indeed. Zaheer Ahmed `myElement!='undefined'` is wrong because you compare jquery object with string. At least you should use `typeof` but I prefer `if (myelement.length)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have an element with

```
id="wizard1" (assuming optionalArg = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug by putting a console.log to ('#wizard'+ optionalArg) and check whether the element exists? most likely the element does not exists and hence creating and error.